# Getting total number of request per minute data from glassfish using nagios check_jmx4perl plugin

Tags: glassfish, monitoring, glassfish-3, nagios

I have **nagios** monitoring system running and gathering details from mysql, glassfish memory footprints, etc...

Now I am trying to fetch the total number of requests that glassfish handles per minute and average response time of those requests.

I have **jolokia** agent installed in **glassfish** cluster and getting memory and other stuff.

> But I have no idea on how to fetch request/reponse data from glassfish
>   using nagios check_jmx4perl plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for an hour, I came up with another tool to monitor total number of request per minute in glassfish, tomcat, etc. It has so many features and not just request and response stats.
You can use nagios to monitor memory footprints and other java heap memory stats but to monitor request, response, throughput, etc, Use the below one

**It's JavaMelody**

https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki